# Macro to warn when a record will expire within 30 seconds

Tags: excel, vba

I found this one which had a same problem. I noticed that the problem was in formated sheet.

I take out the formated and now it work except that when the expire date is far away and there is no need to do anything it popup the "test text" only with out names and days.

If the expires dates is near the range "40" it give the right message with the "test text" and names and days.

```
Sub popup()

    Dim lstRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim msg As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1") ' rename as required

    With ws
        msg = "test text " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        lstRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lstRow
            If .Range("S" & i) - (Date) <= 40 Then
                msg = msg & .Range("B" & i).value & " in " & .Range("S" & i).value - Date & " days" & vbCrLf
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    MsgBox msg
    'Call settimer
End Sub
```

Comment: What line is highlighted when you get the error?

Comment: `LDiff = DateDiff("d", Date, Sheets("Sheet1").Range("S" & LRow).Value)` So what is in column S of your Sheet1? I suspect it is not a number.

Answer (score 0):

Dates are treated as numbers with a *1* for every day past Dec 31, 1899. You don't really need to use `DateDiff` if you are just counting days; you could simply subtract the date in question from Date to get the number of days.

You state that your 'expires dates' are in column C but you are using column S in the code. I'm guessing that this has something to do with it. VBA has an `IsDate` that makes a pretty good guess as to whether a value is a date or not.

That code is pretty old if it is using an `Integer` to govern row numbers. Better to make those long integer to cover an XLSX's 1,048,576 rows (even if you are not using them all right now).

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim LRow As Long
    Dim LName As String
    Dim LResponse As String
    Dim LDiff As Long
    Dim LDays As Long

    LRow = 2   'start at row 2
    LDays = 50 'Warning - Number of days to check for expiration

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        'Check the first 37 rows in column C
        While LRow < 37

            'Only check for expired certificate if value in column S is not blank
            If IsDate(.Range("C" & LRow)) Then
                LDiff = .Range("C" & LRow).Value2 - Date
                If (LDiff > 0) And (LDiff <= LDays) Then
                    'Get  names
                    LName = .Range("B" & LRow).Value
                    LResponse = LResponse & LName & " will expire in " & LDiff & " days." & Chr(10)
                End If
            End If

            LRow = LRow + 1
        Wend
        If CBool(Len(LResponse)) Then _
            MsgBox "These insurance certificate(s) are nearing expiration:" & Chr(10) & LResponse, vbCritical, "Warning"
    End With
End Sub
```

I ran that through some sample data with dates in column C and it seemed to report the names in column B properly for nearing expiration dates.

Comment: @manolisandrianakis - BTW, the code `If (LDiff > 0) And (LDiff <= LDays) Then` doesn't notify on the actual day of expiration since that would be an *LDiff* of *0*. That would seem to me to be the most important day of all.

Comment: Fist of all i want to thak you all for the respond. Now  the LDiff = DateDiff("d", Date, Sheets("Sheet1").Range("S" & LRow).Value) was the line that highlighted. In my sheet the dates are in S coloumn. I test it the new your code but now didn't make problem but at the same time dont do anything. I found another one formula which have a almost same problem and i notice that the problem with this one was my format sheet. After i take out the format of sheet the other one work at least as for 90%.

Comment: @manolisandrianakis - Please do not put code into comments. Edit your original question to add the new code sample.

Comment: @manolisandrianakis - It sounds like your dates are not dates at all; probably text that looks like actual dates. Run Text-to-Columns on column S, choosing Fixed Width, remove all suggested fields and click Finish. If your 'dates' are anything remotely like dates, then this will convert them to actual dates.

Comment: Now its ok. Thank you. It seems there was te problem. Is there any case to find litl time ti check the other one that posted before. Thak you anyway you are profesor for me

Comment: @manolisandrianakis - [Glad you got sorted out](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If you have another question posted, it isn't listed in your profile. You should stick with one profile and build a site reputation with it. If you bounce around between multiple profiles, no one can find relevant questions you've posted and you split your reputation among all of the profiles.

Comment: sory about that but you i am new in this kind and......!! So what if i want to format with a coloure the cell that belong to my castomer and the popup message inform me?  and in case who i have two messages is there any way to inlude all the messages in one popup message? And i mean about the code that you fix me.

Comment: @manolisandrianakis - I've changed the code so that all of the messages get reported at once. As far as coloring the cells, you would be much better off with a conditional formatting rule. These are automatic so that if you change the expiration, the highlight color goes away immediately without manually changing the color or rerunning the macro.